# How do I install old version of homebrew itself, not the formula

Tags: homebrew

I know how to install Homebrew like in https://brew.sh/. It always installs the latest version of homebrew (current version is 2.0.2). I find some incompatibilities between the current and 1.x.

How can I install 1.x version of homebrew?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't recommend this, but you should be able to just checkout the old version of Homebrew in Homebrew directory.

```
# install new Homebrew
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

# Go to Homebrew folder
cd /usr/local/Homebrew

# Checkout old version
git checkout 1.0.0
```

What's the incompatibility you are talking about? I think it is easier to solve your incompatibility than use an old version of Homebrew.